# Notify after 3,6,9 and then 12 months after plugin activation

Tags: date

I save plugin current month with below code on plugin activation. I want that after 3 , 6 , 9 and then 12 months a notification is generated for the user. How can we do that. Below is the code to record the current month and save it in a variable. On everyday on page open I want the plugin to compare the value with the first save date and notify after exact 3 months, then after 6, 9 and 12 months after plugin activation .. How can that be done.

```
$start = date('m');
```

Comment: wish there was a lazy tag over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set a Transient and set its expiration to 3 months.  Once it expires, it can trigger a message or some other behavior that alerts the user about the timeframe.